# $elementMatch query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to find elements which have product.typeCode in ["800", "200", "400"]

```
{
    "_id": "stdcl13@ml.com",
    "_class": "com.mongodb.BasicDBObject",
    "accounts": [{
        "number": "96398-00910620286__DISABILITY",
        "product": {
            "typeCode": "400",
            "nameCode": "401"
        },
        "dependents": [],
        "_id": "stdcl13@ml.com96398-00910620286__DISABILITYDSB"
    }, {
        "number": "96398-00910620286__LIFECNV",
        "product": {
            "typeCode": "300",
            "nameCode": "LIFECNV"
        },
        "dependents": [],
        "_id": "stdcl13@ss.com"
    }]
}
```

I wrote this query, but its not returning the results

```
find( {
    accounts: {
        $elemMatch: {
            product: {
                 typeCode: {
                    $in: ["400"]
                 }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below query. You can add the additional values in the IN clause (800, 200, 400).

```
db.collection.find({ "accounts.product.typeCode" : {
                    $in: ["400"]
                 }
            }
    );
```

**With all three values:-**

```
db.productlist.find({ "accounts.product.typeCode" : {
                    $in: ["400", "800", "200"]
                 }
            }
    );
```